# adding a jquery datatable dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatable

I need to add a datatable dynamically. I can add a html table dynamically, however it is not being converted into a datatable.

I am getting this error:
Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable'
File: test.html, Line: 12, Column: 13

here is the test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="da" lang="da">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/script/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function () {
            var s = "<table id='example'><thead><tr><th>Sites</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>line1</td></tr><tr><td>line2</td></tr><tr><td>line3</td></tr></tbody></table>"
            $('.add_to_this').append(s);
            $('#example').dataTable();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="add_to_this">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the datatables CSS file.

```
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
```

Here is a working [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tallrye/6yhv8q79/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine if you include the `dataTables` css.

Comment: I've updated the code to include the datatables css - but still not working.I get an error message  Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable'

Comment: Quite likely you've not included the `dataTables` JS -- possible path issue. Check the console for any missing files. **AND**  the css url should be `//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css`